# POST request to Google Apps script from Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I am trying to do a post request to google apps script function through a spring boot application and I am getting unauthorized exception.

My spring Boot controller function is as below

```
@PostMapping("/sendInfo/{id}")
    public void sendInfoToGoogleAppsScript() {

        Object object= objectService.findObjectById(id).get();

        String scriptUrl = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<Object> objectHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(object);

       restTemplate.exchange(
                scriptUrl,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                objectHttpEntity ,
                String.class
        );

        System.out.println("Data successfully sent to Apps script");

    }
```

My apps script function is as below

```
function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello World.");
}
```

The error is as below:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:106) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:183) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:932) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:881) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:781) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:663) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
```

-> Tried deploying the script as web app
-> Set executable as User accessing the web
-> Set who has access to anyone within my organization (as I dont have any other options except only myself)
-> Also tried other combinations for above mentioned, but still the issue persists.

Can anyone suggest answers to this problem or suggest any alternatives(except using Apps script API)?

Comment: In the case of `Set executable as User accessing the web -> Set who has access to anyone within my organization`, it is required to request Web Apps by including the access token in the request header. In this case, it is required to include a scope of Drive API. Also, if the users cannot directly access your Google Apps Script project, it is also required to share it with the users.

Comment: can we do it without using any API?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `can we do it without using any API?`. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: The problem with me is, I cannot create any google cloud project to integrate Apps script API or include a scope of Drive API. So I am expecting a solution without using an external API. Can you give me a sample code to achieve this if possible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The problem with me is, I cannot create any google cloud project to integrate Apps script API or include a scope of Drive API.`, I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Do you know any other way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256960/discussion-between-lohith-and-tanaike).